# Computing row average of columns with same name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
    a   a   a   b   b   b   c   c   c
0   1   2   3   0   1   2   1   3   5
1   4   5   6   3   4   5   2   4   6
2   7   8   9   6   7   8   3   5   7
```

I have a dataframe with multiple columns with the same name, and I want to create a new dataframe with the calculated means of the rows with the same column name.

Following is the desired output:

```
    a   b   c 
0   2   1   3
1   5   4   4
2   8   7   5
```

I tried the following code, but it did not seem to work.

```
df_mean = df.groupby(by=df.columns, axis=1).mean()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by level parameter:

```
df_mean=df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).mean()
```

another possible way:

```
df_mean=df.T.groupby(df.columns).mean().T
```

output of `df_mean`:

```
    a   b   c
0   2   1   3
1   5   4   4
2   8   7   5
```